# C# xml to keypair value

Tags: c#, xml

I have a problem which cant solve anymore and need a fresh insight. I need the following XML structure to become  keypair values.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
   <page>
     <title>Home</title>
     <url>http://data.home.nl</url>
     <page>
         <title>link 1</title>
         <url>http://data.home.nl/link1.aspx</url>
         <page>
            <title>link 2</title>
            <url>http://data.home.nl/link/link2.aspx</url>
            <page>
               <title>link 3</title>
               <url>http://data.home.nl/link/link/link3.aspx</url>
            </page>
            <page>
               <title>Test 4</title>
               <url>http://data.home.nl/link/link/test4.aspx</url>
            </page>
            <page>
               <title>Test 5</title>
               <url>http://data.home.nl/link/link/test5.aspx</url>
            </page>
            <page>
               <title>Test 6</title>
               <url>http://data.home.nl/link/link/test6.aspx</url>
            </page>
            <page>
               <title>Test 7</title>
               <url>http://data.home.nl/link/link/test7.aspx</url>
            </page>
         </page>
      </page>
   </page>
</data>
```

What i need to achieve is the  and  in a keypair value, i'm lost....

Thanks!

*updated xml sorry

Comment: The XML seems broken. And do you have some class to deserialize into?

Comment: Your XML example has incorrectly nested elements, and the root element isn't closed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [get key value pairs from xml using linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716004/get-key-value-pairs-from-xml-using-linq)

Answer (score 1):

As Shyju has already pointed out, your XML is not well formatted.  I also assume you meant the element to be `title` instead of `titel`?  I used `titel` in the answer since that is what you had in your XML string.

I believe you can achieve your result using [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx):

```
var xmlString = // set your xml string here
var xml = System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Parse(xmlString);

var myDictionary = xml.Elements()
    .Select(e => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
        e.Element("titel").Value, 
        e.Element("url").Value))
    .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);
```

**EDIT**

I see you have edited you question and the pages are actually hierarchical.  To handle this, you could create a LINQ extension method to handle recursion:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Recursive<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, 
    Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> recursiveFunc)
{
    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        yield return item;
        var result = recursiveFunc(item);

        if (result != null)
        {
            foreach (T nextItem in Recursive(result, recursiveFunc))
            {
                yield return nextItem;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then create your dictionary like this:

```
var myDictionary = xml.Elements()
    .Recursive(e => e.Elements())
    .Where(e => e.Element("title") != null && e.Element("url") != null)
    .Select(e => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
        e.Element("title").Value, 
        e.Element("url").Value))
    .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v=> v.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd create a list of Page entities and deserialize it:

```
[XmlRoot(name="page"]
public class MyPage
{
    [XmlElement(name="titel")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(name="url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize into:

```
List<MyPage> pages;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is **not valid**. You may check it [here](http://validator.w3.org/)

Assuming it is a typo and you have valid XML in the below format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
    <page>
       <titel>link 3</titel>
       <url>http://data.home.nl/link/link/link3.aspx</url>
    </page>
    <page>
       <titel>Test 4</titel>
       <url>http://data.home.nl/link/link/test4.aspx</url>
    </page>           
</data>
```

Then you can use **LINQtoXML** to query it and do whatever you want

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary =    new Dictionary<string, string>();

var path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/pairs.xml");

XElement elm = XElement.Load(path);
//you can also load the XML from a stream /Textreader etc..

if (elm != null)
{       
    foreach (var page in elm.Elements("page"))
    {
        var title = page.Element("titel").Value;
        var url = page.Element("url").Value;
        dictionary.Add(title, url);
    }
}
//dictionary is filled now
```

I am sure you will add proper Error Handling (always include `null` checking before accessing the element to apply some method or read property value)

Answer (score 0):

Your xml is in recursive form.

If need to store parent-child relationship, use Nested Class instead of Dicitionary

```
public class Page 
{ 
    public string Title { get; set; } 
    public string Url { get; set; } 
    public List<Page> childPage {get; set;}
}
```